# Does casting an IEnumerable to an IList<TResult> enumerate the sequence, and why would this be preferred?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

In some decompiled source from [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/), I found this interesting snippet in the body of `FirstOrDefault()`, defined after a quick validation check:

```
  IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
  if (list != null)
  {
      if (list.Count > 0)
          return list[0];
  }
  else
  {
      using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
      {
          if (enumerator.MoveNext())
              return enumerator.Current;
      }
  }
```

I find two curiosities in this.

First, would this enumerate the source?  It seems obvious that it would given that the `.Count` property is defined for an IList, but what if the underlying sequence itself happens to be lazy?

Second, if it does enumerate the source, why would this be a chosen implementation?  Wouldn't it make more sense to simply use the code that follows `if()` check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are completely correct that *in theory*, a 'lazy' sequence *could* implement `IList<T>`, resulting in the `Count` property-access unnecessarily enumerating the entire sequence, only for the generated items to be thrown away. In this case, the 'optimization' chosen by FirstOrDefault would actually make things worse.

But in practice, only sequences that are collections that can provide *fast* access to items by index are usually expected to implement `IList<T>`. This is why, for example, `LinkedList<T>` does not implement this interface even though it could provide all of the functionality required by it.

That said, this FirstOrDefault optimization isn't really a big performance win for lists. At best, it prevents allocating an enumerator object on the heap. Not performing this optimization would not have been the end of the world.

Comment: Is there anything which documents a promise that `IList<T>.Item(0)` must return the first item of the enumerator?  Given the lack of any other interface for a collection whose items can be read and written via an integer index, it would not seem implausible that a sparse-array type might have an enumerator which would yield only items that had been written.  Not a great design, perhaps, but it would allow such a type to be used in some sensible ways that would otherwise not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not enumerate anything. It just checks if the object instance in `source` implements `IList<TSource>` and uses that interface instead.

The point of this interface is most probably optimization, because accessing the element directly is better than using the enumerator.

And if you want to know more about how LINQ is implemented, check Jon Skeet's [EduLinq](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/edulinq/).

Answer (score 0):

> First, would this enumerate the source?

No, it would not. If this underlying collection is an `IList<T>`, that means it always keeps an updated `Count` property reflecting the collections size, which is a `O(1)` operation. No need to enumerate. I haven't encountered a lazy collection implementing the above interface, since that would violate the users assumption that a `Count` property is a a no enumerating operation.

> Second, **if it does enumerate the source**, why would this be a chosen implementation?

This doesn't matter, as no enumeration is being performed, just a simple cast.